# How to download a file programmatically from Jupyterlab?

Tags: python, bash, ipython, jupyter-lab

I generated a zip file in Jupyterlab which I'd like to download via bash, python or ipython. I don't mind the language / environment as long as I can execute the command from a cell.

I am connecting to Jupyterlab remotely and the server ist hosted by another company (Celonis).

I couldn’t find much about this topic - this usually means my search terms are wrong or this is not supposed to be done.

Any ideas?

Comment: Download file from where to where? From the JupyterLab deployment to your local computer? From internet to the JupyterLab deployment?

Comment: From the remote JupyterLab deployment to my local computer.

Comment: Just an idea: right click on fie in the File Browser -> `Copy Download Path`, add token if you have one, then write some simple code to generate a link in that format  programatically if needed and use wget? In principle it should work, but a lot will depend on your configuration (are you accessing a server in public domain, or behind an ssh proxy? is it configured to use tokens, or passwords? etc)